# Oracle procedure to check if file exists on a web server

Tags: c#, oracle, file-exists

I have a site that I call an oracle procedure and within it I create html code to put in my dynamic process in "C#".  The html code creates a link to a pdf file.

Everything is working great until I was asked to put a check that the files exist on the web server and if not do not show the link.  Is this possible to do in oracle?  If not would I have to change my entire approach now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UTL_FILE.FGETATTR()` on the server side.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003493

Comment: Thank you Peter.  That is what I was looking for.

Comment: Sure thing Jerry. If you are having any problem using `UTL_FILE`, remember to check the parameter in the Oracle server that defines the root directory for `UTL_FILE` to operate in.